# Polymorphic one to many in spring jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

If I have 2 entities a User and a Place and they each have a @onetomany relationship to an entity called Photos, what is the best way to do this? I was thinking there would be a type column on the photos table to provide the polymorphic relationship but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you struggle with exactly ? In your use case, I don't see the need of having polymorphism, but of course, there isn't enough information in your question as of now, try adding pieces of your code, of SQL of your tables for example.

Comment: I actually just got it working by making my Photo class abstract and User and Place using their own version of Photo using single table inheritance. This is creating a type column with a fk for place and user entities.